# How to build an application using cmake file?

Tags: compiling, cmake, github

I have downloaded an application from Github and following the instructions given there to 'build' my tool (https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool/tree/master/scripts_to_build).

Right now I'm trying to compile the application using steps given in that page,

```
cd ..
mkdir x64
cd x64
cmake -DQT5_DIR=/path/to/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

but I see the following error

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/opt" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

What is going wrong? Ubuntu noob here, please help out! Thanks!

Comment: Probably the first `cd ..` is erroneous (or should be `cd PixelAnnotationTool`) - you need to run the `cmake` command from one directory level below `PixelAnnotationTool` such that `../` contains the `CMakeLists.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

See in the directory where it's "/path/to"

On linux that generally means replace that with wherever it is on your system.

as a general thing on linux just do cmake .. (to make the contents of the folder above) and then do make. Sometimes you'll need to cd .. for this to work because it won't move it to your current directory.